# google chrome headless puppeteer get DOM of page

Tags: google-chrome, headless, puppeteer

Hello I want to get content of page.
I use page.content() from doc. Still that gets me not DOM after render and process by javascript but source code,
I want to be able grab iframe and generated by javascript content like it was from devtools chrome.
I also try:

```
let bodyHTML = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
```

That also gives me source code.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the iframe, but using this code u can get the inner Text. This worked for me.

```
    const body = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return {
            'body': document.body.innerText
        };
    });
    console.log('body:', body);
```

Comment: I get as document.body still that gives me me some kinda object. I try print it all by uti.inspect but it can't read it no idea why,

Comment: document.body returns object only. get inner HTML document.body.innerHTML it will return the HTML content of the url and u will find iframe and its source

Comment: i did that and get as return some kinda strange object name like so jQuery13133123:16 but i can't  print any element inside it. I try json.stringify, node.inspect still i get no results. anyreson why I can't print it ?